# Give permissions of LDAP group files to specific user

Tags: linux, permissions, ldap, access-control-list, nss

Here is the situation:

- I want user *usr* to have the same permissions of a group *grp*, anywhere in the system.
- *grp* is not a local group, it comes from a LDAP server, of which I have no control over.

I don't have much experience with Linux, so I did some research and found two possible ways to accomplish this:

- Create a local group with the same name and make *usr* a part of it. However, I'm  not too sure about how this would impact remote users from the original *grp*. Would I need to make changes to the NSS configuration file in order for this to work correctly? In that case, what should the configuration be?
- Use ACL to give *usr* permissions. My problem with this is that it seems kind of complicated. As far as I know, there's no automatic way to do what I want, I would have to make a script that traverses the filesystem, checking the group permissions of every file and directory, and then giving *usr* the same permissions. Am I missing something or this would be the only way?

Comment: Why not add _usr_ to group _grp_?

Comment: I'm new to this, so I'm sorry if I'm not understanding it correctly. But *grp* comes from a LDAP server, it's not actually a local group defined in /etc/group. I don't have access to the LDAP server so I can't change its database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done without modifying the LDAP database. You *can* add local users to LDAP groups, but it must be done on the LDAP server.

The problem is that local groups and LDAP groups are different "worlds". A system can be configured to use both, but one of them will be a primary, and the other a secondary. If something is found in the primary source, the secondary will not be asked. This makes your first way a no-go: the local *grp* would overshadow the LDAP group (or, if the LDAP is the primary, it would just be ignored altogether).

The second approach could work, however, it is as you said: complicated, resource-extensive (traversing the filesystem can generate a lot of IO), fragile, and more like a hack than an actual solution.

I think the best way would be to ask the admin of the LDAP server to include the user in the *grp* group. Also, I might be wrong here, but it feels like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: I found your answer pretty useful, but I don't think my question qualifies as a XY problem (although I didn't even know the expression before and I might be wrong). I offered my attempted solution but I also stated what is the general problem I'm trying to solve. I try to do that in order to show I was not lazy, but maybe it'd be better to just describe the problem instead. Thanks.

Comment: Please, I want to make something clear: I never thought you to be lazy, or your question not to be well written to describe the problem. I apologize if it sounded this way, it wasn't my intention. I thought this to be an XY problem, because you asked about getting access, and getting access is _usually_ a means, not an end. but it might well be that you were just curious, so again, I can be wrong about the XY part.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification, I understand your point. I was indeed curious to learn more about how things work, apart from solving the original problem. Your answer was very helpful :)